# Multipart identifier couldnot be bound

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am am getting error when trying to execute the below code, please help me

```
If Convert.ToString(Session("userType")).ToLower() = "admin" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=Maintenanceinfo.userid) AS userid, (SELECT Category_Name FROM Maintenance_Category WHERE Category_Value=Maintenanceinfo.Category_Value) AS Category_Value, Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December from Maintenanceinfo where year = " & dt1 & " Order by Category_Value"
ElseIf Convert.ToString(Session("userType")).ToLower() = "manager" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=a.userid) AS userid, (SELECT Category_Name FROM Maintenance_Category WHERE Category_Value=Maintenanceinfo.Category_Value) AS Category_Value, Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December from Maintenanceinfo a,UserDetails b where a.userid=b.userid and b.Managerid= " & Session("userId") & " and year = " & dt1 & " Order by Category_Value "
Else
        cmd.CommandText = "select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=Maintenanceinfo.userid) AS userid, (SELECT Category_Name FROM Maintenance_Category WHERE Category_Value=Maintenanceinfo.Category_Value) AS Category_Value, Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December from Maintenanceinfo with (nolock) where userid= " & Session("userId") & " and year = " & dt1 & " Order by Category_Value "
End If
```

The error generated is `The multi-part identifier "Maintenanceinfo.Category_Value" could not be bound`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure the column name is spelled correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, presumably, with the second statement (although you really ought to have gone through a little effort to help us work out which of *three* separate SQL statements are raising the issue).

The SQL is:

```
select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=a.userid) AS userid,
   (SELECT Category_Name FROM Maintenance_Category WHERE             
         Category_Value=Maintenanceinfo.Category_Value) AS Category_Value,
    Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August,
    September, October, November, December
from Maintenanceinfo a,UserDetails b
where a.userid=b.userid and b.Managerid= " & Session("userId") &
    " and year = " & dt1 & "
Order by Category_Value
```

Where the error is being caused by this subquery:

```
(SELECT Category_Name FROM Maintenance_Category WHERE             
         Category_Value=Maintenanceinfo.Category_Value)
```

Because the name `Maintenanceinfo` isn't in scope at this point because, for this query, you've introduced an alias for this table - `a`. So the correct query ought to be:

```
select sno, b.UserName AS userid,
   (SELECT Category_Name FROM Maintenance_Category WHERE             
         Category_Value=a.Category_Value) AS Category_Value,
    Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August,
    September, October, November, December
from Maintenanceinfo a
        inner join
     UserDetails b
        on
           a.userid = b.userid
where b.Managerid= " & Session("userId") &
    " and year = " & dt1 & "
Order by Category_Value
```

I've also switched to ANSI join syntax rather than `,` in the `FROM` clause - They've only been in the standard for 20+ years...

I've also removed a subquery that's not required since you're already joining to the `UserDetails` table.